# angular2 data binding not working?

Tags: json, object, xmlhttprequest, angular

So i am trying to pass `record` variable to other components.

I have read json data using `http provider` and successfully stored it in variable name `record` using below code.
I am facing problem while accessing this object in template of the component.
i.e.

**1.left-sidebar.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit,Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {ComponentBarComponent} from "./../component-bar/component-bar.component";
import { DataService } from '../../../app/services/data.service';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'left-sidebar',
    directives:[ComponentBarComponent],
    providers: [DataService],
    template: `
    <div style="overflow-y:auto;height:62vh;">         
        {{record | json}}  //this prints record object in json format correctly
        {{record.name}}  //but this line produces exception       
        <component-bar [record]="record"></component-bar> 
        //also this object is not getting passed to component-bar object.       
    </div>`
})

export class LeftSidebarComponent implements OnInit {        
    public absolutePath:string;
    record:Object;
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { 
        this.componentName="Heading";
        this.absolutePath="http://localhost:8080/src/app/lib/component-group.json";        
        this.dataService.getData(this.absolutePath)
        .subscribe((data:any[]) => {
            this.record = data;                
            console.log(this.record.name);//this prints component name correctly
        });          
    }
    ngOnInit() {        
     }
}
```

**2.component-group.json**

```
{
    "name": "components",
    "desc": "components",
    "libName":"Standard",
    "components": [
        {
            "name":"HeadingComponent",
            "desc":"",
            "cmpType":"Standard",
            "imgUrl":"http://localhost:3202/uploads/ABC.png",
            "cmpLocation":"",
            "isDynamic":"true"          
        },
        {
            "name":"BodyComponent",
            "desc":"",
            "cmpType":"Standard",
            "imgUrl":"http://localhost:3202/uploads/pqr.png",
            "cmpLocation":"",
            "isDynamic":"true" 
        },
        {
            "name":"FooterComponent",
            "desc":"",
            "cmpType":"Standard",
            "imgUrl":"http://localhost:3202/uploads/erter.png",
            "cmpLocation":"",
            "isDynamic":"true" 
        }    
    ],
    "createdBy":"ABC",
    "updatedBy":"ABC"
}
```

When I use `{{record | json}}` it prints json data correctly but when I trying to print it like `{{record.name}}` but its producing the following exception

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in [ 
    {{record | json}}        
    {{record.name }}           
     in LeftSidebarComponent@22:43]
```

any suggestions?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The http call is asynchronous. The reason you are probably getting an undefined reference error is because the template is being rendered before the http call has a chance to return.

Try doing this:

```
{{record?.name }}
```

This ensures that if record is undefined, it will not produce an error. When the http call eventually returns and record is assigned a value, the expression will be re-evaluated to show the expected result.

Comment: I am able to access the variable this way.but I will require to iterate over this object.will it be feasible to access it without '?' as it will be difficult to apply '?' each time? any way to wait until record is completely initialized?

Comment: You could use *ngIf="record != undefined" on a parent DOM element